# Pig If Else semantics

Tags: apache-pig

I have something like

```
a = LOAD 'input-1';
b = LOAD 'input-2';
c = UNION a,b;
```

where input-1 is a directory and may be sometimes empty. Whenever it is empty, the UNION throws some exception as a is NULL. UNION is just one operation here, it could be any other operation like JOIN a BY $0, b BY $0, etc.

Is it possible to check the nullness of "a" in Pig, before using it any sub sequent operation ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pre-process your inputs using the SPLIT function.  There are no if/else semantics in Pig, unfortunately.

```
a = LOAD 'input-1';
b = LOAD 'input-2';

SPLIT a INTO a_clean IF ($0 is not null), a_dirty IF ($0 is null);
SPLIT b INTO b_clean IF ($0 is not null), b_dirty IF ($0 is null);

c = UNION a_clean, b_clean;
```